# Modify macro to highlight overwritten cell

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to modify the VBA code below so that if the macro overwrites a cell then it will be highlighted so we can go back and check it. For example: if we had the word ‘cardboard’ before the word ‘car’ the program overwrites the answer to cardboard with the answer to car given that it has the same letters so it shows up in our filter, I want this cell to be highlighted so that we know it changed an answer.

Thank you so much for your help!

```
Sub filter()

Dim i As Integer
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim lastrows As Long
Dim rngs As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set rng = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells
Set rngs = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells

lastrow = rng.Find(what:="*", after:=rng.Cells(1), lookat:=xlPart, 
LookIn:=xlFormulas, Searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious, 
MatchCase:=False).Row
lastrows = rngs.Find(what:="*", after:=rngs.Cells(1), lookat:=xlPart, 
LookIn:=xlFormulas, Searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious, 
MatchCase:=False).Row

If (Sheets("Sheet2").AutoFilterMode And Sheets("Sheet2").FilterMode) Or 
Sheets("Sheet2").FilterMode Then
Sheets("Sheets2").ShowAllData
End If

For i = 3 To lastrows
searchfor = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value
Category = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("$A$2:A" & lastrow).AutoFilter field:=1, 
Criteria1:="=*" & searchfor & "*"

With Sheets("Sheet2")
    headerrow = .AutoFilter.Range(1).Row
    lastfilterrow = .Range(Split(.AutoFilter.Range.Address, ":")(1)).Row
    getfilteredrangetoprow = .Range(.Rows(headerrow + 1), 
.Rows(Rows.Count)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Row
    If getfilteredrangetoprow = lastfilterrow + 1 Then 
getfilteredrangetoprow = 0
End With

If getfilteredrangetoprow <> 0 Then
    For Each Cell In Sheets("Sheet2").Range("b3:b" & 
lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        Cell.FormulaR1C1 = Category
    Next Cell
    End If

Next i

If (Sheets("Sheet2").AutoFilterMode And Sheets("sheet2").FilterMode) Or 
Sheets("sheet2").FilterMode Then
Sheets("Sheet2").ShowAllData
End If



End Sub
```

Comment: So, what is your question? Please read> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: why are you even asking? why does your code change the value in a cell and then does **not** change the color right after?

Comment: This code is very sloppy... You should create a variable for your WS, I'm seeing a few typos with `Sheets("Sheet2")` (maybe?) in here that may be causing issues. I'm not surprised you're having issues with this code

Answer (score 0):

You can find several ways to highlight a cell in

> http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/highlight-active-cell.html

```
Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0

Cells(i, columnNumberValue).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
```